# LIKE in INNER JOIN doesn't work

Tags: sql

While practicing in SQL here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join i made up a task for myself - need to compose a table using INNER JOIN that will contain CustomerID, EmployeeID, ContactName of a customer, and employee's last and first names WHERE Employee's first name is contained in Customer's contact name. The following doesn't give an output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.ContactName AS CustomerContactName, Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.FirstName AS EmployeeFirstName, Employees.LastName AS EmployeeLastName
FROM Customers
JOIN Employees
ON Customers.ContactName LIKE "%"+Employees.FirstName+"%"
```

Though this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.ContactName AS CustomerContactName, Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.FirstName AS EmployeeFirstName, Employees.LastName AS EmployeeLastName
FROM Customers
JOIN Employees
ON Customers.ContactName LIKE "%Janet%" AND Employees.FirstName LIKE "%Janet%"
```

gives correct output for just one case. Do i miss something or it is w3schools' issue?

Comment: Change on clause to below..ON Customers.ContactName LIKE (select '%'+Employees.FirstName+'%')

Comment: I think you need to provide an example of your data in each table that you expect to join up. The Query itself looks like it should work so it's likely the issue is your data

Comment: The two queries are not comparable, If first name was `Janette`, and contact name was `Janet Jackson`, then the both values satisfy `LIKE '%Janet%'`, but `Janet Jackson` does not contain `Janette`, so the join condition is not met.

Comment: mhn, this one doesn't work either. Seems there are  some limitations on w3schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.ContactName AS  CustomerContactName, Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.FirstName AS EmployeeFirstName, Employees.LastName AS EmployeeLastName
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Customers.ContactName LIKE "%"+Employees.FirstName+"%"
```

Results in:

```
Number of Records: 3
CustomerID  | CustomerContactName   | EmployeeID    | EmployeeFirstName | EmployeeLastName
41          | Annette Roulet        | 9             | Anne              | Dodsworth 
67          | Janete Limeira        | 3             | Janet             | Leverling 
68          | Michael Holz          | 6             | Michael           | Suyama
```

Looks like you've got to explicitly tell it that it is an inner join. though this should not be necessary. thats w3schools for you!

Comment: I used the link that you provided. It does seem very flaky, but I've added the result set to show you that with persistence it does work.

Comment: It is really very strange. Nevertheless i accept your answer.

Comment: Well, i've opened this page in another browser and finally got this query working. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work for me. My mysql server version is 5.6.25.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that the two queries are not comparable, If first name was `Janette`, and contact name was `Janet Jackson`, then the both values statisfy `LIKE '%Janet%'`, but `Janet Jackson` does not contain `Janette`, so the join condition is not met.

Secondly, I think you should be using single quotes for literals, not double, e.g. '%' + Employees.FirstName + '%'.

I am not sure what engine w3schools is running, but with the above change, and changing `JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` which are equivalent I got results:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        Customers.CustomerID, 
        Customers.ContactName AS CustomerContactName, 
        Employees.EmployeeID, 
        Employees.FirstName AS EmployeeFirstName, 
        Employees.LastName AS EmployeeLastName
FROM    Customers
        INNER JOIN Employees
            ON Customers.ContactName LIKE '%'+Employees.FirstName+'%';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your actual data, I can't really be sure what's actually happening in your case, but there is a flaw in your first query:

```
Customers.ContactName LIKE "%"+Employees.FirstName+"%"
```

This will only return records where the `Customers.ContactName` contains the *entire* `Employees.FirstName`.

For example, if you have an `Employees.firstName` = "Jonathan", then it will only return records where there is a `Customers.ContactName` that contains the entire value "Jonathan", not just some part of it.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what i'm intending to get - e.g. if there's an Employee with FirstName="Janet" (there actually is) and Customer with ContactName="Janete Limeira" - that will be a match.